# How to create a method for a mongoDB connection, and write query in different method in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, methods

I have created a method for MongoDB connection and I am able to print all document from the collection.

```
    public static void connectMongowithURI_1() {

        String db_name = "YYYY", db_col_name = "XXXX";

        String client_url = "mongodb:localhost XXXXX";
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(client_url);

        // Connecting to the mongodb server using the given client uri.
        MongoClient mongo_client = new MongoClient(uri);

        // Fetching the database from the mongodb.
        MongoDatabase db = mongo_client.getDatabase(db_name);

        // Fetching the collection from the mongodb.
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection(db_col_name);
        //log.info("Fetching all documents from the collection");
        System.out.println("Fetching all documents from the collection");

        BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        whereQuery.put("SyncAccount.DataArea.GeneralInfo.AccountBusinessKey",101871);

        //FindIterable<Document> cursor = coll.find(whereQuery);
        // Performing a read operation on the collection.
        FindIterable<Document> fi = coll.find(whereQuery);
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = fi.iterator();

        try {
            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                //log.info(cursor.next().toJson());
                System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

But when I created two separated methods, one for to make a connection and another for to write query.

This method is for making connection to MongoDB.

```
public static MongoClient connectMongowithURI() {

    String mongoURI = "mongodb: XXXYYY";
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(mongoURI);
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
    System.out.println("MongoDB is Connected");
    return mongoClient;
}
```

This method is for the Write query. But This is not working. Can Anyone please help me to solve this problem.

```
public static void findAllDocument(String dataBaseName, String collectionName) {

    MongoDatabase db = connectMongowithURI().getDatabase(dataBaseName);
    System.out.println("Connected_1");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
    System.out.println("Connected_2");

    BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    whereQuery.put("SyncAccount.DataArea.GeneralInfo.AccountBusinessKey",101871);
    System.out.println("Connected_3");

    //FindIterable<Document> cursor = coll.find(whereQuery);
    // Performing a read operation on the collection.
    FindIterable<Document> fi = collection.find(whereQuery);
    System.out.println("Connected_5");

    fi.noCursorTimeout(true);    // ERROR MESSAGE GENERATE AFTER THIS LINE.
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = fi.iterator();
    System.out.println("Connected_6");

    try {
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            //log.info(cursor.next().toJson());
            System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
        }`enter code here`
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Here is Exception: (Console report)

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorize. at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:735)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:725)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:463)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:725)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:89)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:189)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:143)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
at dB.connection.ConnectToMongoDB.findAllDocument(ConnectToMongoDB.java:80)
at dB.connection.ConnectToMongoDB.main(ConnectToMongoDB.java:21)
```

Comment: When you say it's not working please share the exception and the exact cause to help you further.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorize

Comment: _Catch_ the exception at the "`enter code here`" at the try-block. Look for examples on the net on how to use "try-catch-finally". In the `catch` block do `printStackTrace()` - this will get a detailed exception message. Update the post with the message.

Comment: The `mongoURI` value in the method `connectMongowithURI()` looks different from the one in the `connectMongowithURI_1()`'s `client_url`. Also see this post with similar error: [Mongo Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404509/mongo-query-failed-with-error-code-13-and-error-message-not-authorized).

Comment: So the error itself explaining that the connection is refused due to not authorized request.

Comment: @ShankarSaranSingh The first method are working fine. But when I make second and third method are not working. i am using same configuration for both method.

Comment: Would be better if you make mongo_client static and available at class level, and check if the mongo_client connection is active before you start the operation on this object, if client connection is not active then call the same method again and create a new connection from it, would be much better if you create a connection pool of client objects.