# Mongo db admin is not authorized to execute commands

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jhipster

I have created a user in the admin db with the following command:

```
db.createUser({user: 'username', pwd: 'pass', roles: [ { role: 'root', db: 'admin' }] });
```

After I added the command in mongod.conf as follows:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I am connecting to the MongoDB from spring boot and my connection in the yml as follows:

```
data:
    mongodb:
      authentication-database: admin
      database: test_db
      host: host
      password: pass
      port: 27017
      username: username
```

but when I run the program I get an error saying the follows:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized on test_db to execute command { find: "system.indexes", filter: { ns: "test_db.dbchangelog", key: { changeId: 1, author: 1 } }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true, $db: "test_db" }' on server host:27017
```

Can anyone able to help me to reslove this issue?

Comment: I believe it might help you,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404509/mongo-query-failed-with-error-code-13-and-error-message-not-authorized

Comment: In which db did you create the user? See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I created on the Admin table.